# How do I delete rows based on a condition on factor variable in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with multiple variables and a factor variable that has the name of the segment like Seg1, Seg2, Seg3, etc.

The names of the segments are unique and there is a total of 11 segments and I would like to drop the records of a few segments.

Since this is a factor variable, how do I drop the records that meet the criteria. The levels I want to drop are 1,2,5,6,7. Please help me in how do I drop the rows where the segments are of these levels.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[as.numeric(df$var) %in% c(1,2,5,6,7), ]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a general answer.

```
# Generate a factor variable
# to provide an example.
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
        mutate(
                cyl_factor = as.factor(
                        paste(cyl, "cyl")
                )
        )
```

I would convert the `factor` to `character` in this process, to avoid dealing with missing `levels`, so

```
# Convert factor to character, to 
# avoid factor levels confusions. And 
# filter accordingly.
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
        mutate(
                cyl_factor = as.character(
                        cyl_factor
                )
        ) %>% filter(
                !(cyl_factor %in% c("6 cyl", "4 cyl"))
        )
```

Where `c("6 cyl", "4 cyl")` will be the `levels` of the factors that you want to exclude from your data.